# Sharepoint 2010: Create web pages programmatically of multiple solutions

Tags: sharepoint-2010, multiple-instances, sitetemplate

My problem goes, as the title says, create web pages programmatically of multiple solutions on SharePoint 2010; because when I do deploy one solution the program recognize my site templates and I can create without problems, but when I do deploy two solutions the program not recognize second site templates. Normally I have **50 site templates on 1033** and **each solution add 3 templates to 1033**, but at the end **I only find 53**.

```
this.webTemplates = site.RootWeb.GetAvailableWebTemplates(1033);

int a = this.webTemplates.Count;

//a = 53    =(
```

When I re-run the application I find the 56 templates but I need to make deployment both solutions in one and found all templates. So, there some service I have to restart or update some element?

Thanks in advance! And sorry if my English is not so good.